# Using $group and filter queries together

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of this sort

```
{
    "_id" : <id>,
    "USER" : <user1>,
    "LIST" : <array>,
    "TIME" : 1234
},
{
    "_id" : <user1>,
    "USER" : <id>,        
    "LIST" : <array>,
    "TIME" : 1233
},
{
    "_id" : <user3>,
    "USER" : <id>,        
    "LIST" : <array>,
    "TIME" : 1230
},
{
    "_id" : <id>,
    "USER" : <user4>,
    "LIST" : <array>,
    "TIME" : 1234
},
{
    "_id" : <user5>,
    "USER" : <id>,        
    "LIST" : <array>,
    "TIME" : 1233
},
```

In the end, I want a array of these documents but grouped by the `TIME` field, i.e., if the two `TIME` fields are same they should be in the same object. I also want it to be filtered by `USER` field. I should be able to pass an array and only those documents should be passed back who have values in the array. For example if I pass an array `[user1, user2]` it should only pass back results, grouped by time, who have user values either `user1` or `user2`. It would be nice to also have the count of the number of documents in the group.

like for example

array passed : [user1, user4]

```
[
    {
        "TIME": 1234,
        "COUNT" : 2            
    },
    {
        "TIME": 1233,
        "COUNT" : 1            
    }

]
```

How do I accomplish this? `$in` is a query operator and `$group` is an aggregate operator. I am looking for a way to combine these two.

Comment: Aggregation pipelines have "multiple" stages. `$match` is a pipeline stage and `$group` is a pipeline stage. This is literally on the very first page of the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Like Neil say in the comment, you can use the aggregation pipeline like this :

```
db.YourCollection.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id: {$in: arrayOfIds}}},
    {$project: {
        TIME: "$TIME"
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: null,
        TIME: "$TIME",
        COUNT: {$sum: 1}
    }}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
                USER: {
                    $in: ['user1', 'user4']
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    TIME: '$TIME'
                },
                COUNT: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $project: {
                TIME: '$_id.TIME',
                COUNT: 1,
                _id: 0
            }
        },

    ]



);
```